# VBA - Error using variable in getElementsByClassName

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" (Run-time error '438') error when I try to use a variable to specify which element in a list of classes to use.

```
For tdNum = 0 To 1000
    If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")(tdNum).getElementById("no-piece").innerText = ItemNbr Then
            Cells(cell, 2).Value = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")(tdNum).getElementById("col-action").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
            Exit For
    End If
Next tdNum
```

HTML:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" class="prod-somm">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" rowspan="2" class="prod-somm-image"></td>
            <td class="prod-somm-texte" valign="top">
                <a href="/eng/Balance-of-system/Fuse-and-holder/Wohner-31110.000/p/284" id="no-piece">
                    90-FT017
                    <span class="prod-somm-sepno"></span>
                    <span id="panier_fab_284">Wohner</span>
                    <span id="panier_nomanufact_284">31110.000</span>
                </a>
            <a href="/eng/Balance-of-system/Fuse-and-holder/Wohner-31110.000/p/284"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="col-action">
            <div class="prix">
                <span id="panier_prix_284">10.43</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem occurs at `If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")(tdNum).getElementById("no-piece").innerText = ItemNbr Then`

The goal is to make the program run down a list of search results until it finds the item number that matches the one in my Excel spreadsheet, then take the price that corresponds to that item.

**EDIT:**
Here is the entire code. Might make what I'm trying to do a little more clear.

```
Option Explicit

Function priceGetRematek()

 Dim XMLHttpRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
 Dim cell As Integer
 Dim tdNum As Integer
 Dim ItemNbr As String
 Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    'Login to Rematek
  With XMLHttpRequest
   .Open "POST", "https://rematek-energie.com/eng/customer-login/account-authentication.php", False
   .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   .send "name_se_connecter=se_connecter&zebra_honeypot_se_connecter=&courriel=rob@solacity.com&motpasse=password&connexion=Sign in"
  End With

'Debug.Print XMLHttpRequest.responseText

    'Get Price Element from HTML
  Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

  For cell = 2 To 38

      ItemNbr = Cells(cell, 1).Value

      With xhr

          .Open "POST", "https://rematek-energie.com/eng/pg/1/r/" & ItemNbr, False
          .send
'Debug.Print xhr.responseText

          If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
                Set document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
                document.body.innerHTML = .responseText

                For tdNum = 0 To 1000
                    If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")(tdNum).getElementById("no-piece").innerText = ItemNbr Then
                        Cells(cell, 2).Value = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")(tdNum).getElementById("col-action").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next tdNum

          Else
                MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .readyState & vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
          End If

      End With

  Next cell

End Function
```

Comment: `("prod-somm")(tdNum)` that syntax can't be correct. What if you remove `("prod-somm")` like `getElementsByClassName(tdNum)`

Comment: But what would be the point of a getting elements by a class name if the programmer can't specify a class name?

Comment: This is over my head. Didn't think VBA syntax allowed two `()`s back to back.

Comment: @findwindow it's used for accessing elements of a collection or array directly. Instead of `Set x = d.getElementsByClassName("a"): Set y = x(1)` you can just do `Set y = d.getElementsByClassName("a")(1)`

Comment: @MacroMan I was just testing you =P

Comment: Do you know that the collection being returned will actually have 1001 elements?

Comment: Are you using Late Binding? `GetElementsByClassName` requires early binding

Comment: @MacroMan, yeah, the 1000 is just because I want it to keep looking until it finds the right element. I wasn't sure how to give it an infinite end, so I figured 1000 (or 1001, rather) tries was more than enough. If you know a better way, I'm all ears. This is my first VBA program, I'm a bit of a newbie

Comment: @Kyle, my terminology is somewhat lacking. Early binding is when you define a variable to be a specific type, right? Rather than leaving it as an object and setting it later? If so, yes I'm using early binding

Comment: You will need to use a `For Each` iteration or test how many items are in the collection. Unrelated to this issue but I imagine that's caused by nested elements in the HTML doc. Will test when I'm at a computer.

Comment: @MacroMan technically you're correct, but it depends how it's instantiated, it won't work with createobject

Comment: @MacroMan yes it is. Try it. This isn't IE automation, it's a different object. It's an oddity for sure and it shouldn't be true, but it is. I wrote a post on it somewhere, I'll dig it out for you.

Comment: @MacroMan this isn't the place for the discussion, I'll post in your forum - it's going a bit off topic

Comment: @MacroMan won't be tonight anyway mate, I'm out with my girlfriend and she's calling me sad ;)

Comment: id attributes are supposed to be unique for any given document - dies that id really show up multiple times in a page?  How many tables are there like the one you show ?

Comment: Every result on the page has that ID. Normally there is only one result, but in the instances where there are more the ID's of these elements are identical

Answer (score 1):

The method `getElementById` is only available on the html document and not on an html element.
But since you have duplicated ids, your best option here is probably to get the targeted element with `querySelector`.
Note that the standard impose a unique id, but it is not enforced in the browsers.

Here is an example that should get you started:

```
' execute the query
Dim xhr As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
xhr.Open "GET", "https://rematek-energie.com/eng/pg/1/r/5", False
xhr.send

' load the html
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, html2 As Object
Set html2 = html
html2.write xhr.responseText

' scrap the html
Dim elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim element As MSHTML.IElementSelector
Dim link As IHTMLElement

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")
For i = 0 To elements.Length - 1
  Set element = elements(i)

  ' get the link with id="no-piece"
  Set link = element.querySelector("a[id='no-piece']")
  If Not link Is Nothing Then

    ' display the product code
    Debug.Print link.FirstChild.data

  End If

Next
```